# Find Highest Divisible Integer In Set By X

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, math

As the title says I would Like the following:

```
Int32 GetHighest(Int32 Input , out Int32 Total) // function signiture

Set(4,3,2,1)// example
input = 7  // function returns 3 and out Total = 6 ---> correct
input = 7  // function returns 2 and out Total = 6 ---> Incorrect
input = 5  // function returns 2 and out Total = 4 ---> correct
input = 5  // function returns 3 and out Total = 3---> Incorrect
```

So GetHighest should return the result with the highest total if totals are equal then it should return the result with highest divisor.

first example ---> 3 goes in 7 two times. So The Total is 3x2 which is 6

second example ---> 2 goes in 7 three times. So The Total is 2x3 which is 6

third example ---> 2 goes in 5 two times. So The Total is 2x2 which is 4

fourth example ---> 3 goes in 5 one times. So The Total is 3x1 which is 3

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: The algorithm isn't clear to me

Comment: @zerkms OK I made the necessary changes

Comment: @aloisdg I don't even know where to start

Comment: @FabioDelarias not helpful yet. It should return, okay. Go and do it.

Comment: "I don't even know where to start" --- well, you boot your computer, wait for windows to start, then start a music player and a VS. That's how most of us start.

Comment: @FabioDelarias this is your homework I guess.

Comment: Wow, I'm thoroughly confused by your example requirements. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Enigmativity Ok put more Detail

Comment: @FabioDelarias - I'm still confused. Why isn't "4 goes in 5 one times. So The Total is 4x1 which is 4" an example? And, if so, isn't it then the highest divisible integer? You need to make your examples clearer. Also the fact that the first and third examples are "correct" and that the second and fourth are "incorrect" hasn't been explained.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes that's it! instead of returning 2 and 4 it should return 4 and 4. Atleast you understand now... too bad no one else does...sigh

Comment: @FabioDelarias - No, I don't understand. I more confused than before. You need to clarify your requirements. It's not everyone else's lack of understanding - it's your explanation. You need to get it right.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't know about that. Nico Schertler understood the question and posted his answer which I excepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of your code that doesn't require storing intermediate results:

```
private Int32 GetHighest(Int32 y, out Int32 totalMax)
{
    var Set = new Int32[] { 4, 3, 2 };
    totalMax = int.MinValue;
    int itemMax = int.MinValue;
    foreach (var x in Set)
    {
       int total = x * (y / x);
       if(total >= totalMax && (total > totalMax || x > itemMax))
       {
           totalMax = total;
           itemMax = x;
       }
    }
    return itemMax;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private Int32 GetHighest(Int32 y, out Int32 B)
    {
        var Set = new Int32[] { 4, 3, 2 };
        var Totals = new List<Int32>();
        foreach (var x in Set)
           Totals.Add(x * (y / x));  
        var Max = Totals.Max();
        var Maxs = Totals.Select((total, index) => new {T = total, index})
                    .Where(r=> r.T == Max).ToList();
        var Maximum = Maxs.Select(G => Set[G.index]).Max();
        B = Totals[Array.IndexOf(Set, Maximum)];
        return Maximum;
    }
```

I guess if you want something done you have to do it yourself!

Comment: If you just want the maximum, you don't have to store all the intermediate results in memory. Just store the maximum total and maximum number. Furthermore, there is no need to convert `y/x` to a `double`. It is already an `int`, so you then don't need to `Math.Floor()` and `Convert.ToInt32()`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The part about not storing the results in memory I don't understand. thx for the advise on `Math.floor`. Post The code and I will give it as the answer.